# What gets constructed first?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am just wondering about the order of constructions here.
 What will be constructed here first is it theInstanceOfA`or the constructor of B which will call A already?

```
class A {
    public:
    A() { cout << "A ctor" << endl; }
    A(const A& a) { cout << "A copy ctor" << endl; }
    virtual ~A() { cout << "A dtor" << endl; }
    virtual void foo() { cout << "A foo()" << endl; }
    virtual A& operator=(const A& rhs) { cout << "A op=" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    B() { cout << "B ctor" << endl; }
    virtual ~B() { cout << "B dtor" << endl; }
    virtual void foo() { cout << "B foo()" << endl; }
    protected:
    A mInstanceOfA; // don't forget about me!
    };

int main() {
    B X;
}
```

Comment: This is something that you should be able to figure out by yourself, simply by adding some parameter to A's constructor, say an `int`, including it in the message, and then passing a different `int` to each instance of `A`.

Comment: When constructing a derived class with a member and single base class, the base constructor is called/invoked first, then the member's constructor, then the derived constructor.

Comment: So its Base - members - derived?

Comment: No, that's not entirely correct. The constructor is always called first. Now, the constructor may end up default-initializing the class members before the constructor's body gets called, or it may end up initialization the class members according to the constructor's **initializer-list**. Your C++ book should have a full explanation of what initializer lists are, and how they direct the construction of class members.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - constructor initialiser lists affect what constructors of members and bases are called.    They don't affect the order in which those constructors are called.

Answer (score 0):

The order of constructors is:

Base - Members - Derived

Comment: What is "Derived" in this context? How is it different from "Members"? Where does the constructor body fit in here? This answer seems very unclear and incomplete. Edit : Since the question is about order of construction, it would be nice to also specify in what order base types and members are constructed, because the order is specified by the language, and specially for data members it can be unintuitive.